# Methods in main queue

Tags: ios, xcode

Tell me how to execute methods on the main queue

i have 3 metods scale html, after scale hidden WebView

```
- (void)updateContentWidth
{
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"setContentWidth('%d%%')", (int)(self.articleContentWidth*100)]];
}

- (void)updateLineHeight
{
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"setLineHeight('%d%%')", (int)(self.articleLineHeight*100)]];

}
- (void)updateFontSize
{
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"setFontSize('%d%%')", (int)(self.fontSizeRatio*100)]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code, by this you can call any method or block in main thread:

```
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // write or call method here
    });
```

Comment: ox no) in turn perform

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is so short / only code. Would you mind expanding it by adding some text to explain how it solves the problem?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateContentWidth)
                       withObject:nil
                    waitUntilDone:YES/NO-To block/not block the current thread];
```